# Disable predictive text in QLineEdit password field for Japanese language

Tags: windows, qt

I have a small Qt code in which we get password from the user.

Now when i type text in password box it starts predicting text. This happens only in Japanese OS and not in English OS.

How can i disable text prediction?
also it shows text in password field !!

[image]

**Code**

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QHBoxLayout>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QMainWindow *window = new QMainWindow();

        window->setWindowTitle(QString::fromUtf8("QLineEdit Password Style"));
        window->resize(336, 227);

        QWidget *centralWidget = new QWidget(window);
    QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout();

    centralWidget->setLayout(layout);
    QLineEdit *lineEdit = new QLineEdit(centralWidget);

    //Set QLineEdit Echo Mode Here so that
    //asterisks will be shown when values are entered
    lineEdit->setEchoMode(QLineEdit::Password);
    lineEdit->setInputMethodHints(Qt::ImhHiddenText| Qt::ImhNoPredictiveText|Qt::ImhNoAutoUppercase);
    //lineEdit->setAttribute( Qt::WA_InputMethodTransparent, true );


    //Add to horizontal layout to center qLineEdit
    layout->addWidget(lineEdit);
    lineEdit->setFixedSize(300, 20);

    window->setCentralWidget(centralWidget);

    window->show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: what's the encode format? I suggest you save the file with utf-8 style

Comment: I have't applied any explicit encoding. Problem is with textbox, which is providing suggestions for any text i enter.